# What are the risks of changing the name of a SQL Server table, temporarily using an empty dummy table, and then changing it back?

Tags: sql-server

In order to solve an issue. I need to check what happens when a table has no rows. My plan:

- Take table 'Foo' --> script table as --> New Query Editor Window --> save as 'FooCopy'
- rename table 'Foo' to 'FooOriginal'
- rename the empty 'FooCopy' to 'Foo'
- Test what I need to test
- Rename 'Foo' to 'FooCopy'
- Rename 'FooOriginal' to 'Foo'
- drop 'FooCopy'

Can this influence a Microsoft Access application, stored procedures, or something along those lines, or would this be relatively safe? (assuming I am the only person using the DB)

Comment: Any reason why you don't just do the whole test on a different server, or at least a backup database restored under a different name? The best way of making sure you don't inadvertently break things is to leave them alone. SQL Server 2014 SP2 and 2016+ have a new `DBCC CLONEDATABASE` command that makes it easier to copy only the schema of a database, in case size is an issue.

Comment: It doesn't harm as long as don't do this on a live database which is being used by application. Doing on a dev database or local is safer but doing this in production would hamper the application functionality and data in the database big-time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that FooOriginal does not already exist or the rename table 'Foo' to 'FooOriginal' will fail as will the following rename and the test will be made on the original Foo Table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're the only one using the DB, it seems rather safe to test it like that. But it feels like a dirty fix. It might be better to copy the table first. Just to be sure.